# Android No view found for id when using toolbar button

Tags: android, kotlin

when i click to toolbar button, galleryFragment should open thats what i want to do. But i got these error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f080051 (com.example.myapplication:id/container) for fragment GalleryFragment{e255e88 (923e67b6-0b21-4fac-acf1-f85b79a3311a) id=0x7f080051}
```

My button id is: `shop`
you can see my codes in `onOptionsItemSelected` function.

do you have any ideas about it?

this is my MainActivity:

```
package com.example.myapplication


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var manager = supportFragmentManager


    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)
        toolbar.setTitle("deneme")


        val fab: FloatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.fab)
        fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show()
        }
        val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
        val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow,
                R.id.nav_tools, R.id.nav_share, R.id.nav_send
            ), drawerLayout
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }


    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)

        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

        when (item.itemId) {

            R.id.shop -> {
                var GalleryFragment = GalleryFragment()
                var transaction = manager.beginTransaction()
                transaction.add(R.id.container, GalleryFragment) //->
                transaction.commit()

            }

        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}
```

This is my main xml(include my button):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/shop"
    android:title="shop"
    android:icon="@drawable/shop"
    app:showAsAction="always">

</item>

</menu>
```

this is my mainactivity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">


    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <include layout="@layout/toolbar">

    </include>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: where does this view came from `toolbar`

Answer (score 0):

create a framelayout or any other view and set id as
  android:id="@+id/container" in your activity_main.xml layout file 
then issue will be fixed.

Reason :  R.id.container id  is not found in your activity_main.xml file

```
  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Hello, ı created navigation drawer fragment automaticly. so ı edit my activity_main.xml. Can you check it please? @alokMishra

Comment: @akiilhan please also add app_bar_main file

Comment: or add above framelayout view in your app_bar_main layout . I hope it will work

Comment: ı find i solution. Actually the problem is, as i told you i created navigation drawer activity automaticly. So, everything is include different xml. If app_bar_main.xml, content_main.xml etc. would be just one xml, it will work. now, i wrote R.id.nav_host_fragment" and it works. Thank for your advice.